# Java LibGDX InputProcessor Multi Touch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
        player1.touchPosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
        camera.unproject(player1.touchPosition);
    }
}
```

It's working but I want to use InputProcessor with touchDragged event.

How can I convert this code to InputProcessor?

Comment: Why don't you try to follow the instructions in the documentation and if you have trouble post your code? Otherwise you're just asking us to repost the documentation.

Comment: Should I use for loop for InputProcessor? I didn't understand InputProcessor.

Comment: No, the callbacks happen when events happen.

Comment: I couldn't find at documentation. There is only methods at documentation. My english is not well, so I asked for help here. Could you give me an example about pointers please. I could find only videos about InputProcessor but i cant understand english without sub-titles and there is no source about libgdx in my country.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    if (pointer < 20) {
                player1.setTouchPosition(new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(pointer), Gdx.input.getY(pointer), 0));
                camera.unproject(player1.getTouchPosition());        }
    return true;
}
```